# Old website and redirect old URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I just upload my new website, and i would like to do some 301 redirections for the SEO.

My old website had URL like : http://www.myoldwebsite.com/contact/?lang=fr, http://www.myoldwebsite.com/accueil/?lang=fr, http://www.myoldwebsite.com/photos/?lang=fr

I would like to do some redirections :

http://www.myoldwebsite.com/contact/?lang=fr **TO** http://www.myoldwebsite.com/contacts

http://www.myoldwebsite.com/accueil/?lang=fr **TO** http://www.myoldwebsite.com/accueil

http://www.myoldwebsite.com/photos/?lang=fr **TO** http://www.myoldwebsite.com/gallery

I made redirections like this in my .htaccess but it's impossible to combine several redirections ...

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /contacts/$
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*)
>
> RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/contact/? [R=301,L]

How to make it ?

Thanks a lot :-)
Have a nice day !

Comment: Look into .htaccess rewrite url

Answer (score 0):

http://www.htaccessredirect.net
I haven't give it a try but this might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you should use multiple `RewriteCond` conditions in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*photos\/?
RewriteRule (.*) /gallery? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*contact\/?
RewriteRule (.*) /contacts? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works !!! Thanks :-)
But with the "contacts" rewrite rule, it redirect to /contacts?lang=fr. Is it possible to remove the get parameter ?

Comment: Please if my solution works, then vote and mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: So what about your problem and my .htaccess code above?